# How to share HttpClient GET with BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, behaviorsubject, rxjs-pipeable-operators

So, I was utilizing shareReplay(1) to cache the array of Items in memory that are returned from an HttpClient GET call.

```
if (!this.getItems$) {
    this.getItems$ = this.httpClient
            .get<Item[]>(url, options)
            .pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
return this.getItems$;
```

I'm doing this because I have many components on the page that need the array of Items and I don't want to make the http call for each one.

I am also creating an Item on the page.  So, after I make a call to the service to call the API which creates the Item in the database and returns it, I would like to add it to the array of Items in memory and alert all the components that are subscribing to the updated array.  So, I tried this:

```
private items = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>(null);
```

...

```
if (!this.getItems$) {
this.getItems$ = this.httpClient
    .get<Item[]>(url, options)
    .pipe(
      tap({
        next: (items) => {
          this.items.next(items);
        },
      })
    )
    .pipe(multicast(() => this.items));
}
return this.getItems$;
```

Then in the method that calls the API:

```
return this.httpClient.post<Item>(url, item, options).pipe(
      tap({
        next: (item) => {
          this.items.next(this.items.value.push(item));
        },
      })
    );
```

The issue is, that anything that is subscribing to the getItems method, is always returning null.  There are items in the database, so even on the first call, there should be items returned.  There are, as I tested it with the shareReplay(1) and it works.

How can I share utilizing a BehaviorSubject instead of a ReplaySubject?

Comment: "*anything that is subscribing to the getItems method, is always returning null*" - Do subscribers initially receive `null`, then the results from `httpClient.get()`, or only `null`?

Comment: Only null.  The item array never has items.

Comment: From the looks of it, the API is not being called with the multicast().  Looking at the documentation, I need to somehow call connect() to subscribe the BehaviorSubject to the source, i.e. the get, which would cause the API to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this code:

```
if (!this.getItems$) {                 
    this.getItems$ = this.httpClient 
            .get<Item[]>(url, options)
            .pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
return this.getItems$;
```

This: `this.httpClient.get()` is asynchronous. So if `getItems$` is not yet set, it won't yet be set by the return statement.

The code is executed in order as follows:

- Line 1.
- Line 2 & 3
- Line 5. (returning null)
- Line 4. (actually processing the returned response)

Also, adding the `if` is redundant with the `shareReplay` that will automatically get the data only if the Observable is not yet set.

Try something like this:

```
getItems$ = this.httpClient
            .get<Item[]>(url, options)
            .pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

**EDIT: Where the above code is a property, not within a method.**

For the second part of the question regarding creating new items, you could do something like this, which is from one of my examples. You can rename the properties/interfaces as needed for your scenario.

```
  // Action Stream
  private productInsertedSubject = new Subject<Product>();
  productInsertedAction$ = this.productInsertedSubject.asObservable();

  // Merge the streams
  productsWithAdd$ = merge(
    this.productsWithCategory$,  // would be your getItems$
    this.productInsertedAction$
  )
    .pipe(
      scan((acc: Product[], value: Product) => [...acc, value]),
      catchError(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
```

You can find a complete example with the above code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-RxJS/tree/master/APM-Final

**EDIT:**

For reference, here is the key code from the stackblitz:

**Service**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { merge, Observable, Subject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, scan, shareReplay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Item } from './item.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemsService {
  url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

  // This is a property
  // It executes the http request when subscribed to the first time
  // And emits the returned array of items.
  // All other times, it replays (and emits) the items due to the shareReplay.
  getItems$ = this.httpClient.get<Item[]>(this.url).pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("I'm only getting the data once", JSON.stringify(x))),
    tap(x => {
      // You can write any other code here, inside the tap
      // to perform any other operations
    }),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
  
    // Action Stream
  private itemInsertedSubject = new Subject<Item>();
  productInsertedAction$ = this.itemInsertedSubject.asObservable();

  // Merge the action stream that emits every time an item is added
  // with the data stream
  allItems$ = merge(
    this.getItems$,
    this.productInsertedAction$
  )
    .pipe(
      scan((acc: Item[], value: Item) => [...acc, value]),
      catchError(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  addItem(item) {
    this.itemInsertedSubject.next(item);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from './item.model';
import { ItemsService } from './items.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html'
})
export class ItemComponent {

  // Recommended technique using the async pipe in the template
  // With this technique, no ngOnInit is required.
  items$ = this.itemService.allItems$;

  constructor(private itemService: ItemsService) {}

  addItem() {
    this.itemService.addItem({id: 42, name: 'Deborah Kurata'})
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<h1>My Component</h1>
<button (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
  <div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried not using the if and it made a call per subscriber.
`this.getItems$ = this.httpClient.get<Item[]>(url, options).pipe(shareReplay(1));

return this.getItems$;`

Comment: Can you create a *small* stackblitz that demonstrates your technique and your issue (not your entire application). It should not be making a call per subscriber. And note that the `return` statement will *not* return the result because the `.get` is asynchronous.

Comment: Yeah, I'm returning the Observable<Item[]>.  The get should not fire until the first subscriber subscribes.  I'll try to get a Stackblitz project.

Comment: Great, thanks! As a property, it won't fire until the property is subscribed to. I have a full example in the above referenced GitHub repo. (I have several YouTube videos and a Pluralsight course on these topics if you are interested in links.)

Comment: To be sure which behavior you want from sharereplay I  would use the newer syntax sharereplay( { refcount : false , buffercount :  1 } ) refcount = false will keep results even if no subscriptions left. Depends on which behaviour you want offcourse

Comment: Here's the example project.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sharereplay-example?file=src/app/items.service.ts  I point to a test api that returns Users instead of items, but it does the job.  If you look at the Network tab in Dev Tools, you'll see it make 3 calls, one for each ItemComponent.

Comment: I made the change I described above and it works as required, only getting the data one time. Revised stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sharereplay-example-g77pay

Comment: Here is a video that talks through this technique: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck

Comment: Ok, I see it isn't making the call multiple times, but two questions.  One, how would you pass parameters to that call and/or add logic inside?  Logic ex: I need to show or not show loading spinner depending on a flag sent to the method and it needs to add to the options.  Two, I tried your merge example. (I updated my Stackblitz example.) But, it is not alerting the subscribers that it has changed.

Comment: For the merge, see my updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sharereplay-example-g77pay I also added a comment showing where you would put in any other code/logic you'd need to add. For these streams to all work as you want them to, they need to be "alive" as properties and not executed within a method.

Comment: How would you utilize parameters with the GET calls?  The only way I can think would be to call a method that would set properties or make the properties public that the GET call would assume were set prior to being subscribed from.

Comment: Could you create that as a new question since I'm being asked to avoid extended discussions in comments. Then I can answer it as an answer instead of as comments. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I created it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67512084/787958

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, I was able to find a solution.

First, I had to get the latest version of rxjs:

```
npm install rxjs@latest
```

Then, I created a shareBehavior class:

```
export function shareBehavior<T>(
  behaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<T>
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return share<T>({
    connector: () => behaviorSubject,
    resetOnError: true,
    resetOnComplete: false,
    resetOnRefCountZero: false,
  });
}
```

Then, in the service:

```
private items = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>([]);
```

...

```
if (!this.getItems$) {
  this.getItems$ = this.httpClient
  .get<Item[]>(url, options)
  .pipe(shareBehavior(this.items));
}
return this.getItems$;
```

This works pretty well.  But, the issue with this was that because behavior has a default value, all the subscribers are sent the initial value of [].  They are updated as soon as the API call finishes.  But, I'd rather utilize ReplaySubject so that the subscribers only get a value when the http get returns.  Do do this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67508863/787958